# Plot phase portrait of a system of ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, system-variables

I have the following system of 4 differential equations:

```
x'[t]== f1[x[t],y[t],z[t],u[t]]
y'[t]== f2[x[t],y[t],z[t],u[t]]
z'[t]== f3[x[t],y[t],z[t],u[t]]
u'[t]== f4[x[t],y[t],z[t],u[t]]
```

Using `NDSolve`, I've solved it numerically with some given parameters. I want to plot the phase portrait only in the $y-z$ plane. How can I do it in a similar way as using `StreamPlot`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! You should provide the whole code, together with your functions `f1, f2, f3, f4`. Also, there are already several questions here about phase portraits, have you tried [searching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=phase+portrait)?

Comment: You want to plot a 2D slice of a 4D space.  Do you want to plot a single trajectory from `NDSolve` or the whole flow field from `StreamPlot`?   If the latter, how should the other two dimensions be treated?

Answer (score 1):

As functions of t you can plot the projections simply by taking two coordinates

```
V[t_] := {Sin[t]*Cos[3 t], Cos[t] Cos[3 t], 
Sin[t]*Sin[3 t],  Cos[t] Sin[3 t]} 

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[V[t][[{i, j}]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
{{i,2}, Range[1, 4]}, {{j,4}, Range[1, 4]}]
```

[image: Trajectories in all 2d projections]

For construction of the 4d vector field one prepares the table of positions and their derivatives with respect to time and tries to expand in an independent set of functions of t

```
VfieldEquations = 
{Equal @@@ 
({{x1, x2, x3, x4}, V[t]}\[Transpose]), 
     Equal @@@ ({{v1, v2, v3, v4},D[V[t], t] }\[Transpose])}\[Transpose]
       // Flatten // TrigExpand

Eliminate[(VfieldEquation//. 
{Cos[t] -> cs, Sin[t] -> sn,cs^n_?Positive :> (1 -sn^2) cs^(n - 2)} // Expand, sn]

v1 == x2 - 3 x3 && v2 == -x1 - 3 x4 && v3 == 3 x1 + x4 && 
 v4 == 3 x2 - x3 && x1^2 == 2 cs^2 - 2 cs^2 x2 - 6 cs^2 x3 + x4^2 && 
 x1 (1 + 2 x2) == (1 - 2 x3) x4 && x1 x3 == (-1 + x2 + 2 x3) x4 && 
 2 cs^2 x2 x3 == -cs^2 x3 - 2 cs^2 x3^2 + x4^2 && 
 2 x2^2 + x2 (-1 + 4 x3) == 1 - x3 - 2 x3^2 && 
 x1 x4 == -2 cs^2 x3 + x4^2 && 
 x2 x4^2 == -2 cs^2 x3^2 + x4^2 - x3 x4^2 && 
 4 cs^4 x3^3 - 3 cs^2 x3 x4^2 == -x4^4
```

So finally fix the plane {x1,x3}={a,b} and StreamPlot the vector field in the {2,4}-plane

```
DV = {x2 - 3 x3, -x1 - 3 x4, 3 x1 + x4, 3 x2 - x3}

 Manipulate[
 StreamPlot[
  DV[[{2, 4}]] /. {x1 -> a, x3 -> b}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x4, -1,1}], 
          {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image: StreamPlot Phase diagram]